# ¿Porque no funciona el espacio de nombre Drawing en c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy empezando a aprender c# y .NET . He intentado hacer una captura de pantalla el problema es que he copiado un codigo para ver si funcionaba pero no me deja usar los objetos del espacio de nombre System.Drawing ni Bitmap ni Image ni ninguna. Esta es la cabecera de mi programa:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

Y al intentar crear un objeto Image me dice esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(No me dejaba copiarlo)

Tampoco me deja usar el espacio de nombre System.Drawing.Common que dice en el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Será una estupidez super obvia para los que sepais pero yo de verdad que no tengo ni idea de lo que puede ser. Por si sirve de algo saberlo he creado un proyecto de WPF.

Comment: Pero ahi dice que los objetos se movieron de namespace a System.Drawing.Common... los estan moviendo en net 6.. y esta en la documentacion tambien...

Comment: @gbianchi ya he intentado importar Sistem.Drawing.Common pero no me deja

Comment: lo tenes que traer de nuget... lo trajiste?

Comment: no XD ahora lo hago y digo si ha funcionado. (tengo que buscar que es nuget y como se hace) muchas gracias

Comment: @gbianchi muchisimas gracias si que ha funcionado

Answer (score 0):

El ensamblado System.Drawing, que es utilizado en el código para manipulación de imágenes en C#, no está disponible en algunas plataformas, como .NET Core o .NET 5+. Si estás utilizando una de estas plataformas, es posible que experimentes errores de compilación relacionados con System.Drawing.

En ese caso, una alternativa sería utilizar una biblioteca de terceros que sea compatible con tu plataforma y te permita realizar la manipulación de imágenes en C#. Por ejemplo, una opción popular es la biblioteca ImageSharp, que es compatible con .NET Core y .NET 5+.

Esperó haberte ayudado.